# Parse a list of html files each containing a table into an excel sheet

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, append

I am trying to parse a list of html files each containing a table to an excel sheet.
I successfully parsed two html files and appended their resulting dataframes like this :

```
import pandas as pd
#Read the first html and adjust header columns

df = pd.read_html(r'C:\Users\A.html')[0].transpose()
new_header = df.iloc[0] 
df = df[1:] 
df.columns = new_header 

#Read the second html and adjust header columns

df1 = pd.read_html(r'C:\Users\B.html')[0].transpose()
new_header = df1.iloc[0] 
df1 = df1[1:] 
df1.columns = new_header 

df.append(df1) 
df1.to_excel(r'C:\Users\My Workbook.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet 1', index = False)
```

However when I add a loop as follows the appending doesn't work:

```
import os
path = r'C:\Users'

# create a main dataframe object to append the other dataframes to 

df = pd.read_html(r'C:\Users\A.html')[0].transpose()
new_header = df.iloc[0] 
df = df[1:] 
df.columns = new_header 

#loop over the html files in the user path

with os.scandir(path) as it:
    for entry in it:
        if entry.name.endswith(".html") and entry.is_file():

            df_temp = pd.read_html(entry.path)[0].transpose()
            new_header = df_temp.iloc[0] 
            df_temp = df_temp[1:] 
            df_temp.columns = new_header 

            df.append(df_temp)
```

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue might be that the `df.append(df_temp)` function does not append the data to the original dataframe in place. You need to save it again into its own variable like: `df = df.append(df_temp)`.

So I'm a bit surprised you're saying your first example is working? Note that there you're doing something very similar, but in addition you're only writing your second dataframe into the excel file with `df1.to_excel()`.

Comment: Yes that was the issue . I think the reason why it didn't appear before was because I was using a Jupyter notebook and probably run one of the cells before where it appended correctly so I was mislead. Thank you for your help